# How to display certain Amazon products in iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-product-api

I have to display list of certain Amazon products in my iOS application. What I am doing now is running search query on Amazon when the list is requested and showing results in web view. However, I don't want to show the search box and all other information on the bottom(navigation, etc..). Question whether Amazon API provides such API for iOS in order to display products? Then user can click on product and then whether new browser open or same web view is not so essential.

Comment: This Amazon API has documentation right?

Comment: My research of API does not reveal anything related to listing products on iOS platform. But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: This API is not available for iOS apps.

Comment: @Pablo > Any update about your question? Did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has the [amazon affiliate marketing program](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html), where they provide html strings for their products. We can use these html strings to display the product info (with or without its picture) in our app using UIWebView. Open the detail product page in Safari on tap of any of the products displayed in the app by you.

Hope this helps.